# After upgrading spring boot from 2.5.4 to 2.6.7, stack traces vanish

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, log4j2

after migrating an application from spring-boot 2.5.4 to 2.6.7 the detailed stacktraces in my application log dissapeared:

This is the code build with 2.5.4:

```
2022-05-18 08:05:25.742 ERROR 15748 --- [s-clearing-p2-1] d.i.clearing.api.p2.ClearBorderoAsync    : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.idslogistik.ipbackend.db.c03.dom.C3VerSendungDOM.hwts, could not initialize proxy - no Session

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.idslogistik.ipbackend.db.c03.dom.C3VerSendungDOM.hwts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:188)
...
```

With 2.6.7 i only get the following oneliner:

```
2022-05-18 09:48:17.570 ERROR 3676 --- [s-clearing-p2-1] d.i.clearing.api.p2.ClearBorderoAsync    : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.idslogistik.ipbackend.db.c03.dom.C3VerSendungDOM.hwts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
...
```

The Exception itself is okay (and already found and fixed). However, i lack the stacktrace.

Comment: Is this one example of many or is it only this particular exception that's lacking a stacktrace?

Comment: Hello @StephaneNicoll - i just tried it with a manual executed NullPointerException and the stacktrace is missing as well

Comment: There isn't anything in Spring Boot that would suppress the exception that I am awarer of. Can you please share a small sample we can run ourselves?

Comment: Struggling hard to do this - i created a minimal, nearly identical spring-boot project containing the (in my view) relevant dependencies (with starter, lombok and logstash-gelf), but the logging works as expected here. Next thing would be to integrate hibernate (as it is the source of the exception shown above)

Comment: Adding hibernate 5.3.9 (via starter-data-jpa) using a h2 still yields a full stack trace. Any suggestions on where to go next, @StephaneNicoll?

Comment: If you can't reproduce outside of your project, I don't know how to help, sorry.